# UITextView scrolls up after "Speak"

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextview

I have a non-editable UITextView to display some text. Users can select the text in this UITextView and choose the iOS "Speak Selection" functionality (speak button) to read it for them. However, when 'Speak' is done reading the last word, it scrolls up the UITextView. In fact, even if I select just the last word in the text, and choose 'Speak', it scrolls up the UITextView.

I have scrollEnabled set to NO, editable set to NO, and the text is a NSAttributedString.

How can I stop the UITextView to scroll up in this case?

[image: Screenshot for the same]

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment with my reputation, unfortunately I don't have a real answer but a workaround; so far mine is to intercept [UITextView setContentOffset:animated] via method swizzling (http://nshipster.com/method-swizzling/) and avoid calling the original method when needed (this method is called by QuickSpeak function). I guess subclassing would be  cleaner if you can instantiate the view yourself (this is not my case).